# Unable to see sfdx commands in the VSCode command palette but can execute them in the terminal

Tags: salesforcedx

Unable to see sfdx commands in the VSCode command palette but can execute them in the terminal.

Did anyone face the same issue in VSCode

Comment: Have you installed the Visual Studio Code Salesforce Extension Pack? You need that _and_ the SFDX CLI.

Comment: That is already there that's why I am able to run those commands in Terminal

Comment: Do you see anything in the command palette at all? When you use Ctrl+Shift+P?

Comment: @RCS Having the SFDX CLI available at the command line and having its extensions available in VSC aren't the same thing. Please confirm via the Extensions UI in VSC that you have the Salesforce Extension Pack installed.

Comment: Yes Salesforce Extension pack is installed